# At where TCP New Reno set the threshold value once a packet is dropped in NS3

Tags: tcp, ns-3, tcp-new-reno

In TCP New Reno it set the threshold value to half of the current CWND once a packet drop is identified. I need to find the method, that does the task.

In `tcp-l4-protocol.h` it uses `TcpClassicRecovery` as the recovery method. In `TcpClassicRecovery` entering phase, it uses the following code segment to set the current CWND,

```
void
TcpClassicRecovery::EnterRecovery (Ptr<TcpSocketState> tcb, uint32_t dupAckCount,
                                uint32_t unAckDataCount, uint32_t lastSackedBytes)
{
  NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this << tcb << dupAckCount << unAckDataCount << lastSackedBytes);
  NS_UNUSED (unAckDataCount);
  NS_UNUSED (lastSackedBytes);
  tcb->m_cWnd = tcb->m_ssThresh;
  tcb->m_cWndInfl = tcb->m_ssThresh + (dupAckCount * tcb->m_segmentSize);
}
```

Then I assume before calling the `EnterRecovery` method, the cwnd is already updated. I need to find the place that cwnd is updated.

I also updated `TcpNewReno::GetSsThresh` and analyzed the output. But it's also not the method I need as it doesn't cut the cwnd to half.

NOTE: I'm using `seventh.cc` to inspect cwnd. It always drops the cwnd to 1072. The graph I'm getting is also included. What I need to do is drop the cwnd to half of the value once a packet is dropped. Maybe the `seventh.cc` is not using the default `tcp-l4-protocol.h`. If so how I can change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The problem was with the `seventh.cc`. It does not use the default layer 4 TCP protocol.

To run the default layer 4 TCP protocol (TCP New Reno), I found an example, which is `tcp-large-transfer.cc`. It's located in `ns-3.30/examples/tcp/tcp-large-transfer.cc`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a quick note: the code to change cwnd is in the very snippet in your question. Specifically, it is this line:

```
tcb->m_cWnd = tcb->m_ssThresh;
```

Much of the state of a TCP Socket is actually stored in the the `tcb` which is a `Ptr<TcpSocketState>`.